# Correct cardinals vs Stable ordinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I recently learnt about correct and stable cardinals and ordinals.

> A cardinal $\kappa$ is called $\Sigma_n$-correct iff $V_\kappa \prec_n V$.

> An ordinal $\alpha$ is called $\Sigma_n$-stable iff $L_\alpha \prec_n L$.

Apart from one being a cardinal and the other being an ordinal, is there really any difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, note that stability is a very, well, **stable** notion: since the $L$-hierarchy is appropriately absolute, if $\alpha$ is $n$-stable in $V$ then $\alpha$ is also $n$-stable in every generic extension $V[G]$. This is very false for **correctness** (this is a good exercise - think about e.g. starting with $V=L$ and then forcing a failure of $\mathsf{GCH}$ above what $V$ thinks is the smallest $2$-correct cardinal).

So even at a very coarse level - "How much can these notions be affected by forcing?" - we see a fundamental difference. Relatedly, by [Tarski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) the class of pairs $(\alpha,n)$ such that $\alpha$ is $n$-correct is never (parameter-freely-)definable in $V$, but the class of pairs $(\alpha,n)$ such that $\alpha$ is $n$-stable may be definable in $V$ (if $V$ is very far from $L$ - e.g. if $V\models$ "$0^\sharp$ exists").

Comment: Great, thanks! I don't really understand forcing however, I just have a vague idea.

Comment: Additionally, $V_\alpha$ must be correct about which ordinals are cardinals (i.e. for $V_\alpha\vDash"\beta\textrm{ is a cardinal}"$, it's necessary that $\beta$ actually is a cardinal), but $L_\alpha$ isn't. That's why we can have things like a countable $\alpha$ where $L_\alpha\vDash\mathsf{ZFC}$, because for some countable $\beta<\alpha$, $L_\alpha\vDash"\beta\textrm{ is a cardinal}"$.